# How to check mime type and upload in different dir

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, mime-types

```
private $uploadhost = "http://my.domain.com/";

function upload()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
    $key = "mykey";
    $redirect = "http://domain.com";
    $Date = date("Y-m-d_H-i-s");

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/robot.txt") {
        die("User-agent: *\nDisallow: /");
    }

    if ($this->input->post('key')) {
        if ($this->input->post('key') == $key) {
            $target = getcwd() . "/r/" . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
                $filename = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                $filename = $filename[sizeof($filename) - 1];
                rename($target, getcwd() . "/r/" . md5($Date) . "." . $filename);
                echo $this->uploadhost . "up/" . md5($Date) . "." . $filename;
            } else {
                echo "Something went wrong";
            }
        } else {
            header('Location: ' . $redirect);
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: ' . $redirect);
    }
}
```

Hello,

my script from above is working only with images. I want to use it for files like *.exe for downloading after upload. How can I check myme type of file and upload file into different directory. So images are going to /r and files are going to /d and .txt is going to /t like this.

Im working with codeigniter 3 RC and ShareX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please guide with url
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html to upload mime type in codeigniter